# C++ Creating a Half-Filled in Rectangle

Tags: c++

SO I have already created a program that creates a frame of a square or rectangle and am trying to get it to output stars inside the square/rectangle, so it is half filled in. Like this:

```
********
** * * *
* * * **
** * * *
********
```

Here is my code so far:

```
void frameDisplay(int width, int height) { 
cout <<"What should the width be?\n";
cin >> width;
cout <<"What should the height be?\n\n";
cin >> height;
if(width < 2){
cout <<"Width must be greater than two.\n";
cout <<"What should the width be? \n";
cin >> width;
}if(height < 2){
cout <<"Height must be greater than two.\n";
cout <<"What should the height be? \n";
cin >> height;
}
cout << string(width, '*') << endl;
for(int j = 0; j < height - 2; ++j)
cout << '*'<< string(width - 2, ' ')<< '*' << endl;
cout << string(width, '*') << endl;
}
int main(){
  int width=0, height=0;
  frameDisplay(width, height);
}
```

Output:

```
What should the width be?
5
What should the height be?

7
*****
*   *
*   *
*   *
*   *
*   *
*****
```

Comment: And the question would be...?

Comment: How to get my code to output the above picture instead of just creating a frame like my code does

Comment: I edited it to show the output

Comment: Wheree exactly lies your problem? You say you're "trying to get it to output stars inside", but I see no sign of you trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest a bit of restructuring of your code.

Create separate functions to:

1. Accept user input.
2. Fill up the frame data in a `std::vector<std::vector<char>>`.
3. Display the frame data.

And then call them from `main`.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector> 
#include <utility> 

using namespace std;

std::pair<int, int> getUserInput()
{
   int width;
   cout <<"What should the width be?\n";
   cin >> width;

   int height;
   cout <<"What should the height be?\n";
   cin >> height;

   return std::make_pair(width, height);
}

void fillUpFrame(std::vector<std::vector<char>>& frameData)
{
   // Add the logic to fill up the frame data.
}
```

For `displayFrame`, if you have a C++11 compiler, use:

```
void displayFrame(std::vector<std::vector<char>> const& frameData)
{
   for ( auto const& row : frameData )
   {
      for ( auto cell : row )
      {
         cout << cell;
      }
      cout << endl;
   }
   cout << endl;
}
```

Otherwise, use:

```
void displayFrame(std::vector<std::vector<char>> const& frameData)
{
   suze_t rows = frameData.size();
   for ( size_t i = 0; i < rows; ++i )
   {
      size_t cols = frameData[i].size();
      for ( size_t j = 0; j < cols; ++j )
      {
         int cell = frameData[i][j];
         cout << cell;
      }
      cout << endl;
   }
   cout << endl;
}
```

And `main`:

```
int main(){

   // Get the user input.
   std::pair<int, int> input = getUserInput();
   int width = input.first;
   int height = input.second;

   // Create a 2D vector to hold the data, with all the elements filled up
   // with ' '.
   std::vector<std::vector<char>> frameData(height, std::vector<char>(width, ' '));

   // Fill up the frame data.
   fillUpFrame(frameData);

   // Display the frame data
   displayFrame(frameData);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding nicely. For some reason I can't get it to compile in my system

Comment: I forgot `#include <utility>`. That file has the definition of `std::pair`.

Comment: okay thank you ill try it

Comment: im still getting a lot of errors. is this c++ or c++ 11?

Comment: @SillyPenguin420, I added a pre-C++11 version of `displayFrame`

Comment: @SillyPenguin420, you are welcome. Happy coding.